# Need help understanding question about how many languages can fit set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages

I've been viewing the Coursera videos on finite autamata and need some help understanding a question.

> What’s the number of non-empty languages that contain only strings of
>   0's and 1's of length n?

First off do they mean there must be n 0's and n 1's or the combination must be n? For example if n=4 then is `0001` in the language?

I don't understand what is meant by languages? My understanding is a language is the set of all strings that take a DFA from it's start state to an accepted state. I could see the question being how big is the language, but how can you have multiple languages?

The explanation given is

> There are $2^n$ strings of 0's and 1's of length n. In a language
>   specified above, each of these strings can show up or not show up.
>   Excluding the empty case, there are $2^{2^n}−1$ such languages.

Also the statement "There are $2^n$ strings of 0's and 1's of length n." is not apparent to me.

Comment: Presumably a *language* has a set of *words* (i.e. *strings*) and a different language has a different set: extra or fewer or both.

Comment: @Henry but how can both languages describe the same thing?

Comment: For this question I do not think that is an issue.

Comment: For your second part, there are for example  $2^3$ strings of $0$s and $1$s of length $3$: `000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111`

Comment: oh right because each digit can be $0$ or $1$ and there's $n$ of them so $2^n$ ways. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They mean that the total length of the string must be exactly $n$. Given an alphabet $\Sigma$, i.e., a set of symbols, a language over $\Sigma$ is simply any set of finite strings of symbols in $\Sigma$. In this problem $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$, and a language is any set of finite strings of zeroes and ones. Restricting yourself to languages recognized by DFAs would limit you to *regular* languages; the question, however, is about languages in general.

Imagine building a string of $n$ symbols, each of which is $0$ or $1$, one symbol at a time. When you choose the first symbol, there are $2$ possibilities. No matter which choice you make, there are $2$ possibilities for the second symbol, so there are altogether $2\cdot 2$ choices for the first two symbols: $00,01,10$, and $11$. Each time you add another symbol, it can be $0$ or $1$, so you double the number of possibilities. After choosing $3$ symbols, for instance, you can have $000$ or $001$, $010$ or $011$, $100$ or $101$, $110$ or $111$ – a total of $2\cdot 4=8$ strings. Thus, there are

$$\underbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot 2\cdot\ldots\cdot 2}_{n\text{ twos}}=2^n$$

possible strings of length $n$. A language consisting entirely of binary strings of length $n$ must be a subset of this collection of $2^n$ possible strings. A set of $m$ objects has $2^m$ subsets, so this set of $2^n$ strings of length $n$ has $2^{2^n}$ subsets. However, one of these subsets is the empty set, and the question asks for the number of *non-empty* languages, so we need to subtract one to get the desired number, $2^{2^n}-1$.

Comment: Thanks I get it. I may misunderstand what a language is. Isn't it the set of all strings that lead a DFA from a start state to final state, not a subset of this (such as your explanation implies)?

Comment: @Celeritas: What you’re describing is a very special class of languages, the so-called *regular languages*. In the context of formal language theory, a language is a completely arbitrary subset of $\Sigma^*$ for some alphabet $\Sigma$, where $\Sigma^*$ is the set of all finite strings of members of $\Sigma$, whether it can be recognized by a DFA or not. A simple example of a language over $\{0,1\}$ that cannot be recognized by any DFA is the language $\{0^n1^n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ consisting of all strings consisting of some number of zeroes followed by exactly the same number of ones.

Comment: Ok I see my confusion. From [here](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~toida/nerzic/390teched/regular/fa/acceptor.html) "the language accepted by a DFA is the set of strings accepted by the DFA." does this mean the language must include every possible string that is accepted by the DFA?

Comment: @Celeritas: Yes: if you have a particular DFA $M$, then $L(M)$, the language accepted by $M$, is defined to be the set of all strings accepted by $M$. It includes all of those strings and no other strings.